# Keras data generator for images x and continuous y

Tags: neural-network, keras, regression

My use case is doing a regression on images, which is different than most examples.

Is it possible to use one of the canned data generators to yield images from a directory for x and a single integer for y? How would I do so?

I'd also like to shuffle the dataset and do an 80 : 20 validation split.

Comment: This question needs some work, to me it's unclear what you're asking, doing regression of images (not classification) but over what parameter, what types of "canned" data generators? Random / white-noise data generation? a subset of CIFAR-10?. Others thought this question was too broad. Which is also true. Try to frame the question better specially the first part given that the second part that has to do with shuffling is easy to implement.